# Unicode Property Escapes in regex cause errors in Babel

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, babeljs, emoji

I needed a way to split strings with compound emojis into an array and I found a way to accomplish that (see question [Is there still no easy way to split strings with compound emojis into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70524820/1786528)).

The regex I ended up using looks like this:

```js
let regex = /\p{RI}\p{RI}|\p{Emoji}(\p{Emoji_Modifier}|\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}?|[\u{E0020}-\u{E007E}]+\u{E007F})?(\u{200D}\p{Emoji}(\p{Emoji_Modifier}|\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}?|[\u{E0020}-\u{E007E}]+\u{E007F})?)*|./gsu
    words = words.map(word => {
      return word.match(regex)
    })
```

This worked great until a recent update on the server (on which I have very limited influence).
The current package versions are these:

```
next 12.1.6
react 17.0.2
react-dom 17.0.2
@babel/runtime 7.17.7
```

This is the mentioned error message:

```
/node_modules/Sections/Hero/index.js: Failed to recognize value `undefined` for property `Regional_Indicator`.
    at CN (babel.7.12.12.min.js:1:1067100)
    at babel.7.12.12.min.js:1:1067328
    at DN (babel.7.12.12.min.js:1:1067334)
    at e (babel.7.12.12.min.js:1:1068730)
    at babel.7.12.12.min.js:1:1069345
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at e (babel.7.12.12.min.js:1:1069321)
    at babel.7.12.12.min.js:1:1069345
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at e (babel.7.12.12.min.js:1:1069321)
```

Besides `\p{RI}` the same error also triggers for `\p{Emoji_Modifier}` and `\p{Emoji}`.

**Is this a bug in the babel version?**
**Is there a way to make the [Unicode Property Escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) work in this setup?**

There are solutions with a (very) long regex [*see comment by Wiktor*], but if possible I would prefer a way to do it with Unicode Property Escapes. The coverage would be good enough for the use case of this project (https://caniuse.com/?search=Unicode%20property%20escapes).

There is this [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/19303) for next that mentions Unicode Property Escapes, but I'm not sure whether this is relevant for next 12.

Here is a minimal example of what the code is supposed to do (the error is not showing here though)
https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-framework-q4dw1d?file=/src/index.js

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69115223/3832970), the bottom of it. If you need the Emoji v.14.0 version, please let know, I will update.

Comment: I updated it to v.14.0.

Comment: Thank you:) Your solution works and I will use for now. However I was hoping there is a way to not include a regex that is bigger than the entire rest to the component ;) I do not care about IE too much, so if there is a way to use the Unicode Property Escapes / Emoji Properties, I would prefer that. It worked before after all.